# Error when installed a laravel project (disc_free_space)

Tags: laravel

i cant install laravel on Windows 10 and i cant find anything about the error
Last version of Composer, XAMPP.

Can anyone help me?

```
PS D:\Programme\XAMPP\htdocs\projekte> composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog    
Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./blog"
Installing laravel/laravel (v9.2.0)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v9.2.0): Extracting archive
Created project in D:\Programme\XAMPP\htdocs\projekte\blog
> @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Composer\Console\disk_free_space() in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:417
Stack trace:
#0 phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php(353): Composer\Console\Application->hintCommonErrors(Object(Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\LogicException), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#1 phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(171): Composer\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#2 phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php(130): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/bin/composer(88): Composer\Console\Application->run()
#4 C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar(29): require('phar://C:/Progr...')
#5 {main}
  thrown in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php on line 417
```

Comment: Have you updated composer to the latest version? Try `composer self-update --2`

Comment: Yes

D:\Programme\XAMPP\htdocs\projekte>composer self-update --2
Storing "stable" as default update channel for the next self-update run.
You are already using the latest available Composer version 2.3.7 (2.x channel).

Comment: I had the same problem today. I deleted composer directory manually and installed again. But my composer directory was located in user/appData/roaming

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `composer cache-clear` to clean composer local cache. On your pc